# CURL REST GET 401 on EC2 but 200 on Windows

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2

I am using CURL to send a GET request to a private api that uses tokens in the header.  When using CURL on my windows laptop I receive a successful 200 response.  When using CURL on my EC2 Amazon Linux server I receive an unsuccessful 401 response.  The code used on both machines is the same, listed below.  Any thoughts?

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization:Bearer 30601a6dea89ac04803313142048c0ac06876653adca66294fde86f0982a0183" https://api.(PRIVATE).com/users
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are some protection by IP ?

Comment: I don't think there is any IP protection.  I accessed the api 24 hours ago with the same code and the EC2 server has a static IP.  I have a license to use the api and the company confirmed everything looked good on their end.

Comment: Any change if you add the -k parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the -k parameter changed the error from 401 to 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the destination url in quotes in linux:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization:Bearer 30601a6dea89ac04803313142048c0ac06876653adca66294fde86f0982a0183" "https://api.(PRIVATE).com/users"
```